# How to add rotation of image before being uploaded?

Tags: php

Hey all i have seen alot of options on how to rotate the image before being uploaded but the issue i have is i am not pro and i do not understand how to implement it into my codes.

Anyone kind enough to help me out with this?

here is my function to resize image

```
function resize_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = 250; $height = 250;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}
```

Here is my upload part

```
if($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
            {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                $cname = str_replace(' ', '-', $candidate_name);
                $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
                $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/images/".$image_name);
                $image_name= $cname.'-'.time().".".$ext;                
                resize_image($tmp_name,"uploads/images/".$image_name);
                $img = ''.$image_name.'';
            }
```

And here is link to a site which has the option but i do not know how to make it work with my code.
[Text](https://www.tutorialswebsite.com/jquery-to-preview-and-rotate-an-image-before-upload-using-php/)

Comment: These code that you shared are only run AFTER your image is uploaded but before they are saved to your filesystem. Do you want the image rotated BEFORE uploading to your php program? Or before your php program saving the file to your filesystem?

Comment: @KoalaYeung yes, that is what i want i to implant in my code so that if an image is not upright i need to upright it before uploading. please help me out.